# Rails: Is it possible to check if a named scope is valid for a given active record?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scope, rails-activerecord

I'm Using Ruby 1.8.7-p374 and Rails 2.3.18. (Yeah, I know, we're working on it.)

I'm considering dynamically passing a named scope to be used as a condition for an ActiveRecord. Is it possible to check to see if a passed string is a valid named scope for the record?

For Example:

If I have a named scope called :red defined for Car

```
named_scope :red, :condition => ["color = ?", "red"]
```

Then is there some function where I could do

```
Car.some_function("red")   # returns true
Car.some_function("blue")  # returns false
```

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `.respond_to?(:method)` ([documentation here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveResource/Base/respond_to%3F))

In your case :

```
Car.respond_to?(:red)  # => true
Car.respond_to?(:blue) # => false
```

---

**But** you said:

> I'm considering dynamically passing a named scope to be used as a condition for an ActiveRecord

I hope you will not use something like this:

```
# url
/cars?filter=red

# controller
def index
 @cars = Car.send(params[:filter]) if params[:filter].present? && Car.respond_to?(params[:filter])
 @cars ||= Car.find(:all)
```

Guess what woud happen if I use this URL?

```
/cars?filter=destroy_all
```

The `Car` model responds to the method `.destroy_all`, so Ruby calls it on the Car model. **BOOM**, all cars are destroyed!

Comment: I agree that @MrYoshiji that you should be very careful with calling dynamically generated methods on a class.  Do not do it with something from params!  My answer is a bit safer as it tests whether :red is actually a scope rather than simply testing whether the class responds to it ;-)

Comment: MyKlass.send(:generated_relation_methods).instance_methods

Answer (score 3):

Klass.scopes will return a hash of all scopes for that class.  You can see if it's in there - the names are stored as symbols.  eg

```
if Car.scopes[:red]
  ...
```

This will return the scope itself (truthy) or nil (falsy), which is fine for passing/failing an `if` test.  If you literally want either true or false back then you can do !! on it to convert it to a boolean.

```
a_bool = !!Car.scopes[:red]
```

Comment: Thank you for this `Model.scopes` method, didn't know it, can be usefull!

Comment: This is not true for Rails 5. The method `scopes` does not exist and it is simply defined as class method.

Ref: https://github.com/rails/rails/blame/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L190

Answer (score 0):

Check if your scope is present in this list to verify. MyKlass.send(:generated_relation_methods).instance_methods